# How to update jQuery sparklines values without rendering small

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, visualization, sparklines

I’m using `jquery.sparkline.js` v2.4.1. I render it like this:

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3">
  <div class="px-3 py-2 d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="sparklines d-inline-flex" sparktype="line" sparkheight="30" sparkwidth="70" sparklinecolor="#886ab5" sparkfillcolor="false" sparklinewidth="1" values='1,2,3,4,3,2,1' id="hist_sent_trend"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It renders okay. Now I included an AJAX call to get new data and want to update my chart.

I tried this:

```js
$('#hist_sent_trend').sparkline([ 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700 ], $('#hist_sent_trend').sparkline([100,200,300,400,500,600,700], {'sparkheight':30, 'sparkwidth': 70, 'sparktype': 'line', 'sparklinewidth': 1}););
```

But the chart becomes very small. How to update `sparkline` values properly, so that it renders as it used to be before I update the values?

Comment: Can you post generated html and css?  What version of jquery?  What other libraries are you including?  What browsers and devices are you testing on?

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the documentation helped me to figure it out https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-docs

So in my case the proper settings were as such:

```
$('#hist_sent_trend').sparkline([ 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700 ], {
            'type': 'line',
            'height': '30px',
            'width': '70px',
            'lineColor': '#886ab5',
            'fillColor': false,
            'lineWidth': 1,
            'spotRadius': 3
        });
```